# React datepicker issue

Tags: reactjs, time, datepicker, react-datepicker

I tried to filter date manually and I gave date in the field as 20230511 filter didn't work as expected and now I tried to keep / in b/w them as 2023/05/11 date picker has highlighted correct date as 5th may, now when I try to keep "-" instead of / the date picker is show one day prior date as 10th may

below is my code

````
  selected={
    e.BaseDate
      ? moment(e.BaseDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()
      : undefined
  }
  placeholderText="enter"
  dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD" 
  className={
    //somecode
  }
  popperPlacement="auto"
/>```

please let me know how to fix it

though I keep - or / it should work
````